# mysql query to insert the sum of three columns into a new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Mysql table in which I have around 2 million rows.

While I inserted values, I had 3 columns (*subject1, subject2, subject3*) which were having scores in 3 different subjects. I thought when I need to select values, I could use just `sum` and `group by`. However, it is giving me some wrong values and `group by` with `having` clause is proving to be time consuming.

So, I decided, I will just insert another column with the sum of these 3 rows. I altered the table to add this new column (Total_Score). Now, when I run the below query, I get an error as `Invalid use of group function`.

```
UPDATE Person_Score
SET Total_Score = SUM(subject1 + subject2 + subject3)
```

How can I just insert the sum for all the 2 million rows?

Comment: leave out the word sum, or add a group by clause

Comment: Scratch that `group by` shouldn't work at all in an update statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to add the values rather than sum.

```
UPDATE Person_Score
SET Total_Score = subject1 + subject2 + subject3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Person_Score
SET Total_Score = subject1 + subject2 + subject3
```